# Swapping Loop Variables in Nested Loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, swap

Suppose there are 2 lists *l1* and *l2*. I want to print out the pairs *x, y*, with *x <= y* and either *x* or *y* must be from *l1* and the another must be from *l2*.

I have written the following code and run on Python 3:

```
l1 = [1, 5, 6]
l2 = [0, 3, 7]
for member_1 in l1:
  for member_2 in l2:
    if member_1 > member_2:
      member_1, member_2 = member_2, member_1
    print(member_1, member_2)
```

And the output is very weird:

```
0 1
0 3
0 7
0 5
0 3
0 7
0 6
0 3
0 7
```

It seems that the loop variables are something more than just storing the values. What have I missed?

Comment: Huh? What were you *expecting*? The loop variables are working normally...

Comment: what output did you expect ? Output is correct with code but it seems code is not correct with your expectation. Maybe put more `print()` inside to see what's going on in code.

Comment: oh, sorry, lack of sleep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you change the value of member1, and it will not go back to its correct value before the next iteration of the outer loop

to solve this, you can (amongst many things):

```
for member_1 in l1:
  for member_2 in l2:
    print(min(member_1,member_2),max(member_1,member_2))
```

My previous answer did not output the exact result OP had originally asked, it was :

```
for member_1 in l1:
  for member_2 in l2:
    print(sorted([member_1,member_2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [1, 5, 6]
l2 = [0, 3, 7]

for i in l1:
    for j in l2:

        if(i<=j):
            print(i,j)

for j in l2:
    for i in l1:

        if(j<=i):
            print(j, i)
```

yield

```
1 3
1 7
5 7
6 7
0 1
0 5
0 6
3 5
3 6
```

Is this what you want printed out?

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.product()`:

```
import itertools

l1 = [1, 5, 6]
l2 = [0, 3, 7]

print([sorted(tup) for tup in itertools.product(l1, l2)])
# [[0, 1], [1, 3], [1, 7], [0, 5], [3, 5], [5, 7], [0, 6], [3, 6], [6, 7]]
```